# CMake IDE integration: Query list of source files

Tags: cmake, ide

I've been looking at the CMake [IDE integration guide](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/ide-integration/index.html).
One feature I'd expect is to be able to query a list of a target's source files (eg. a list of files added to `target_sources()`). However, the guide does not mention anything like that.

When observing other IDEs, such as JetBrain's CLion, it seems to support that feature as sources that have been added to a target using `target_sources()` are marked with a little blue square.

Is there any way to query a list of a target's source files through the cmake binary? Basically I want to retrieve the [SOURCES target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/SOURCES.html#prop_tgt:SOURCES).

Comment: As far as I understand, you need to use features of specific [CMake generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html). Exactly generator is responsible for which information about targets is stored and in which format.

Comment: Does `get_target_property(your_result_list your_target SOURCES)` not give you the necessary information?

Comment: @vre How would I query this from "outside" a CMake list file. The IDE that receives cmake integration would need to be able to query this information through the `cmake` binary.

Comment: You are right this works only from inside the CMakeLists.txt. Maybe the CMake-file-API especially [this object](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-file-api.7.html#codemodel-version-2-target-object) can be queried from an external application (IDE)? I haven't used that up to now.

Comment: @vre I quickly played around with `cmake-file-api`. This is indeed exactly what I was looking for!
Do you care to make this become an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 3.14 CMake provides the [cmake-file-api](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-file-api.7.html) to query a buildsystems information. It replaces the CMake server mode which is still supported in current version (CMake 3.19 as of writing). The following [codemodel-version-2-target-object](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-file-api.7.html#codemodel-version-2-target-object) seems appropriate for your task to query a target's sources.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!